# Kerberos term definitions

Tags: windows, security, kerberos

I am new to kerberos. I found some [link](http://www.zeroshell.org/kerberos/Kerberos-definitions/) but still can't understand it terms fully and how it should be.

Can anybody please make me understand the following terms?

- Realm
- Kdc
- Principal

I want to know how to mention realm name, kdc name should be in krb5.ini?

I setup active directory in windows server 2012. Where can i find the realm name, principal and all in win server system? I want to authenticate it in windows 8 using command line tool **kinit**.

Give me some idea or example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the terms understandable, we can compare the actual technical term with a domain

Example domain: Driving License

- **Realm:**

  - Authentication administrative domain
  - Each realm has its own Kerberos database which contains the users and services for 
    that particular administrative domain.

    - *Example:* TamilNadu has separate administration. Rather AndraPradesh is a separate realm.
- **Principal:**

  - Entries in the Kerberos database. Each user, host or service is given a principal.

    - *Example:* Each person who applies for the license.
- **Kerberos server - KDC:**

  - Database - Contains the user and service entries (user's principal, maximum validity, maximum renewal time, password expiration, etc.)

    - *Example:* License Applicant's details.
  - Authentication Server(AS) - Replies to the authentication requests from the client, when he is not yet authenticated user must insert a password. The AS sends a Ticket Granting Ticket (TGT) back which can be used further on by the user, without re-entering their password.

    - *Example:* Who checks the license; If expired, we are insisted to renew the old one.
  - Ticket Granting Server(TGS) - Distributes service tickets based on the TGT

    - *Example:* License issuing authority, issues license to us.

Comment: Can you explain how to set the realm name. I mean can we set any name to kdc and realm name in krb5.ini file in windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

In short, Realm is a named scope of security objects within the same security boundary. In Windows, Active Directory domain is realm. Realm name = Active Directory domain name. There are non-Windows realms, for example, implemented in Samba. Samba domain is realm too.

KDC stands for Key Distribution Center and is a network service that supplies session tickets and temporary session keys to users and computers within an Active Directory domain. KDC is responsible for principal (local and foreign) authentication. This link explains KDC role in Active Directory: [Key Distribution Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378170(v=vs.85).aspx)

Principal is an identity and role of a user and acts on the user's behalf. Generic principals are user accounts, computer accounts, security groups. An application may define their own identity types. Principals have assigned permissions, which are necessary to access resources within Kerberos domain. This article explains the role of the Principal: [What Are Security Principals?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780957(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Can you provide me any sample to configure kerberos in windows?

Comment: What exactly you want to configure? There are various tools to configure various aspects of kerberos.

Comment: I want to use it for Hadoop security in windows.

Comment: There is nothing to do with Kerberos iself. You should consult with Hadoop documentation and, if necessary, vendor support. Quick search gave this: http://blog.godatadriven.com/kerberos-cloudera-setup.html

Comment: This link may be more useful: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_15.html

Comment: Hi CryptoGuy, Thanks for the above reference; But I would like to secure my own installed hadoop in ubuntu / windows not with the setup provided by any third party like Cloudera.. Can you help us in any case?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Hadoop.